# How to copy one file to multiple destinations with Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to copy one file to multiple destinations with a bash script. I need loop through a text file to read the destinations and then copy the file to the target.

I tried this:

```
while read -r tpath
do
  cp -p test.file "$tpath"
done < destination.txt
```

It does copy the file to all destinations in the file, but I get the following error...

```
cp: cannot create regular file `': No such file or directory
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or suggest a better way to do it?

Comment: The error message indicates that you have a blank line in `destination.txt`. So it's trying to copy the file to that empty destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
while IFS= read -r tpath
do
  [[ "$tpath" ]] || continue # Ignore empty lines
  if
    [[ -d "$tpath" ]]
  then
    cp -p test.file "$tpath"
  else
    echo "Invalid target directory: $tpath"
  fi
done < destination.txt
```

This will prevent empty lines or non-existent directories from being considered.

As an aside, the `[[ "$tpath" ]]` returns 0 ("true" in shell semantics) if the variable contains a non-null value, and a non-zero value otherwise.  It does the same thing as `[[ -n "$tpath" ]]`.  The `continue` keyword causes the loop to skip to the next iteration, bypassing the rest of the loop.  The `||` logical operator is a (lazy) OR logical operator : it will execute the statement on the right only if the statement on the left is false.  The result of that line is that if `tpath` is empty, the loop will silently skip to the next iteration without executing the rest of the body.

Comment: Correct, except of that IFS setting. Fixed that. Btw, with GNU xargs, it could be `xargs -r -I'{}' cp test.file '{}' < destinations.txt` but the `-r` is a GNU extension.

Comment: @hek2mgl  What is the issue with the IFS assignment?

Comment: What was the reason to use it?

Comment: Thanks much. That worked. A question for you...I can follow the bulk of your script, but can you explain why "[[ "$tpath" ]] || continue" will ignore empty lines?

Comment: `[[ "$tpath" ]]` will be false when `"$tpath"` is an empty string and that's when the right hand side of `||` will be executed - which is `continue` and it causes the loop to skip to the next iteration.

Comment: @user3151788  I updated the answer with additional explanation for that part.  This way of expressing statements is very useful : simple, concise, and readable once your brain becomes accustomed to it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Love coming to this site for timely assistance.

Comment: @hek2mgl `IFS=` prevents leading and trailing whitespace from being removed and a path *could* conceivably end in whitespace...

Comment: @GrishaLevit  My understanding is that when reading a single variable, the line will be read whole into the variable irrespective of IFS.  I do that all the  time, and I assigning `IFS=` just as a way to have a known environment available for read.

Comment: @hek2mgl  Did you suggest removing `IFS=` as simply superfluous (I would agree), or actually wrong (I would like to understand why)?

Comment: @hek2mgl try reading a file with `read` where the lines start and/or end with spaces.  Compare `echo ' x ' > t; read -r r < t; printf '<%s>\n' "$r"; IFS= read -r r < t; printf '<%s>\n' "$r"`.  The first case prints  `<x>` and the second `< x >`.

Comment: @GrishaLevit  If you do not set IFS manually, it may be anything found in the environment.  The default value (at least on my system) will cause leading/trailing whitespace to be stripped, which could be what one wants or not (filenames with leading and trailing whitespace are valid although not widely used, and cannot be accommodated if you trim whitespace).  If I wanted to strip whitespace, I would still manually set IFS manually to make sure the script's behavior is always the same.

Comment: @Fred sorry, my last comment didn't make sense as I forgot who was the editor and who was the OP.  I do think you were correct to add back `IFS=`.